# Impresspages Widget disappears after drag and drop

Tags: php, impresspages

I've seen a strange behavior for a custom plugin. It's skin generates some html and it works fine. As soon as i drop the widget onto the page it is only visible after a page refresh. Same is true when i try to drag the widget to another position.

Has anybody experienced the same issue? I am not sure whether its a bug or i might miss something in my code.

**[edit]** *There is an issue with ipContent()->getCurrentPage()->getId() which is NULL after performing any drag and drop action* **[edit]**

This is my skin file:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">

            <label>
                <input id="auth-email-check-nutzung" type="checkbox"><?php echo ipSlot('text', array(
                    'id' => 'nutzungsbedingungen_' . ipContent()->getCurrentPage()->getId(),
                    'default' => 'Ich stimme den <a href="#">Nutzungebedingungen</a>  zu.',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'id' => 'auth-email-check-nutzung-text'
                    )
                )); ?>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input id="auth-email-check-daten" type="checkbox"><?php echo ipSlot('text', array(
                    'id' => 'datenschutz' . ipContent()->getCurrentPage()->getId(),
                    'default' => 'Ich stimme der <a href="#">Datenschutzerklärung</a>  zu.',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'id' => 'auth-email-check-daten-text'
                    )
                )); ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form class="form" role="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail1" class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <?php if ((ipIsManagementState())) :?>

            <?php
                // Use a simulated Button to edit text and prevent any default button event
                // for user friendly inline editing
                echo ipSlot('text', array(
                    'id' => 'button' . ipContent()->getCurrentPage()->getId(),
                    'default' => 'senden',
                    'tag' => "div",
                    'class' => 'btn btn-danger auth-button btn-block',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'data-target' => 'bs-button',
                        'id' => 'auth-email-button-div'

                    )
                )); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (!(ipIsManagementState())) :?>
                <?php
                // Display real Button only on the live page with the contents of ipSlot :
                // 'id' => 'button' . ipContent()->getCurrentPage()->getId()
                echo ipSlot('text',array(
                    'id' => 'button' . ipContent()->getCurrentPage()->getId(),
                    'tag' => "button",
                    'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'data-target' => 'bs-button',
                        'id' => 'auth-email-button',
                        'disabled' => 'disabled'
                    )
                )); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you reload the page, "currentPage" really exists. That's why the code works. But when you drag a new widget or move the widget, it's content is loaded using AJAX. AJAX request has no real page. So getting current page id in widget's skin is not possible at some points.

Comment: Thank you, i just noticed your comment.